# when is OpenCobol 1.1 going to be released on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

Can anyone give me any idea if and when OpenCobol 1.1 is likely to be released on UBUNTU. The version that comes with Ubuntu does not have many of the commands available such as TRIM, WHEN-COMPILED and numerous other features in 1.1.

Comment: If and when the developers/maintainers of that package submit a new version before the software freeze it will be include in the next version of Ubuntu. Else you'll have to search for a PPA or compile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 and later come with OpenCobol 1.1. It's unlikely that there will be an official package for 12.04 or earlier. Maybe you can find a PPA or backport the package for 12.10 yourself.

Comment: But it's *quite likely* it will be officially packaged as a backport, if the OP [requests the backport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) and is able to test it.

Comment: Changed settings on Update Manager to look for ALL releases of UBUNTU and it then offered 12.10 upgrade option, which worked well to upgrade safely to 12.10 from 12.04. Then changed settings on Update Manger to look for all supported updates. Had to re-install X-ScreenSaver but otherwise everything looks good, and COBOL 1.1-1 now in place.